# Sql query Conversion formula for Ecommerce solutions

Tags: sql-server-2008, math, stored-procedures, select, count

I need to calculate conversion rate in one go , i can get total count values for calculation like , to get total success by the user on the site :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalSuccess FROM Orders Where Success like 'OK'
```

And the for totaltrials made by user an be found :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalTrialMade FROM productTrials
```

How can i do a successful conversation rate , all in one go in a sql, any ideas or assistance will be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: i am using sql server 2008, and i was thinking of doing this all stuff in a store procedure

Comment: For a specific user, you would need to specify that user - otherwise you would get everything recorded on that table, not just for a single user. Are the two tables above actually views? Do they reference the same underlyng table? Can you include table structures in the question?

Comment: well i am looking for total users who visits the site and if they buy the product , which updates the the order table as success , currently i m just selling one product but i will be selling multiple products in future so i have too look into conversion rate for each products later on

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TotalSuccess/TotalTrialMade AS ConversionRate FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalSuccess FROM Orders Where Success like 'OK') AS SuccessCount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalTrialMade FROM productTrials) AS TrialCount
```

Comment: SELECT (TotalSuccess/TotalTrialMade) * 100 , can i do something like this

Comment: Sure you can: `SELECT TotalSuccess/TotalTrialMade*100 AS ConversionPercent ...`

Comment: getting 0% conversion rate :(

Comment: I suspect SQL Server is treating this as an integer division, try `SELECT CAST(TotalSuccess AS float)/CAST(TotalTrialMade AS float)*100.0 AS ConversionRate FROM ...`

Comment: can i pass this to my label text like lblConversionRate.Text = Convert.ToString(conversationRate) + "%";

Comment: Since the output of the calculation is a float, you might want  `lblConversionRate.Text = Math.Round(conversationRate).ToString() + "%";`